# Regex optional and depending on older optional

Tags: regex

I currently have this regex:

```
/^\+\(?([0-9]{1,4})\)?$/g
```

Now, I can use the following formats:

```
+31
+(31)
+(31
+31)
```

However, I want to modify it so only with both parentheses it'll work, not just with one. So `+(31` and `+31)` won't work anymore. How can I manage to get it?

Comment: Which regex engine do you use? Conditionals might be useful here, but are not supported by all engines (e.g. JS). You could also simply alternate: `(?:\d+|\(\d+\))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an alternation group to match digits inside parentheses or with no parentheses:

```
^\+(?:\([0-9]{1,4}\)|[0-9]{1,4})$
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rM84h5/1)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string anchor
- `\+` - a literal `+`
- `(?:\([0-9]{1,4}\)|[0-9]{1,4})` - one of the two alternatives:

  - `\([0-9]{1,4}\)` - 1 to 4 digits enclosed with literal `(` and `)`
  - `|` - or
  - `[0-9]{1,4}` - 1 to 4 digits
- `$` - end of string anchor

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly just the way I want. Cheers! Whenever I can, I'll accept the answer.

Comment: Just FYI: if your regex engine supports a conditional construct, you may use [`^\+(\()?[0-9]{1,4}(?(1)\)|)$`](https://regex101.com/r/fXyMBC/1).

Comment: Thanks for that but it doesn't work in Javascript (just saying) still thanks because it looks a bit cleaner and I still have to check it in PHP too so there I can use this.